# Simply connected covering space of circle with its radius added

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm trying to come up with a simply connected covering space for a circle with its radius added, i.e., a circle plus a line going from one point of the circle to its antipodal point. I know that a simply connected covering space for the circle is $R$, but the addition of the radius complicates things and I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean with its _diameter_ added? It seems so from the rest of your description. This space would be homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of 2 circles, $S^1\vee S^1$, and it is easy to find information about its universal covering space, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738085/covering-spaces-of-wedge-sum-of-circles

Comment: The universal cover of any connected graph is a tree. You can figure out its valence by looking at the valence of vertices of the graph. What do you think it is in your case?